# useSelector() hooks returns undefined value from state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to access the state values from the redux store which returns the correct values for the initial state of the reducer. However when I try to dispatch an action (authenticate) and update the state values then when I try to access the state again it returns undefined values for the state properties (jwtToken & isAuthenticated)

Here's my app component where all the action is happening

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { authenticate } from "./store/slices/userSlice";
import { Store } from "./store/store";

import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";

import OnboardingScreen from "./screens/OnboardingScreen";
import LoginScreen from "./screens/LoginScreen";
import SignupScreen from "./screens/SignupScreen";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import Colors from "./constant/colors";
import FavoriteScreen from "./screens/FavoriteScreen";
import NotificationScreen from "./screens/NotificationScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "./screens/ProfileScreen";
import { StorageKeys } from "./constant/storageKeys";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const BottomTabStack = createBottomTabNavigator();

function AuthStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={OnboardingScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={SignupScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function AuthenticatedStack() {
  return (
    <BottomTabStack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors.raisin_black,
        tabBarLabelStyle: { fontSize: 14 },
      }}
    >
      <BottomTabStack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => {
            return focused ? <Text>Home</Text> : null;
          },
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons
              name={focused ? "home" : "home-outline"}
              color={color}
              size={size}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <BottomTabStack.Screen
        name="Favorites"
        component={FavoriteScreen}
        options={{
          // tabBarLabel: "Favorites",
          tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => {
            return focused ? <Text>Favorites</Text> : null;
          },
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons
              name={focused ? "bookmark" : "bookmark-outline"}
              color={color}
              size={size}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <BottomTabStack.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={NotificationScreen}
        options={{
          // tabBarLabel: "Notifications",
          tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => {
            return focused ? <Text>Notifications</Text> : null;
          },
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons
              name={focused ? "notifications" : "notifications-outline"}
              color={color}
              size={size}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <BottomTabStack.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{
          // tabBarLabel: "Profile",
          tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => {
            return focused ? <Text>Profile</Text> : null;
          },
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons
              name={focused ? "person" : "person-outline"}
              color={color}
              size={size}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </BottomTabStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function setupNavigation(isAuthenticated) {
  console.log("setupnavigation rendered");
  //TODO handle authentication state if user is already logged in
  
  console.log("isAuthenticated", isAuthenticated);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {!isAuthenticated && <AuthStack />}
      {isAuthenticated && <AuthenticatedStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
// Keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

function RootView() {
  console.log("root view rendered");
  const [fetchingToken, setFetchingToken] = useState(true);
  // const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);
  let jwtToken = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.userReducer.jwtToken;
  });
  let isAuthenticated = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.userReducer.isAuthenticated;
  });
  console.log("isAuthenticated=> ", isAuthenticated);
  console.log("jwtToken=> ", jwtToken);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchToken() {
      let jwtToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem(StorageKeys.JWT_TOKEN);
      if (jwtToken !== null) {
        dispatch(authenticate({ jwt: jwtToken }));
      }
      setFetchingToken(false);
    }

    fetchToken();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (!fetchingToken) {
      // This tells the splash screen to hide immediately! If we call this after
      // `setAppIsReady`, then we may see a blank screen while the app is
      // loading its initial state and rendering its first pixels. So instead,
      // we hide the splash screen once we know the root view has already
      // performed layout.
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fetchingToken]);

  if (fetchingToken) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
      {setupNavigation(isAuthenticated)}
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  console.log("app rendered");
  const [isFontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    poppins_light: require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf"),
    poppins_reg: require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf"),
    poppins_med: require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf"),
    poppins_semi_bold: require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf"),
    poppins_bold: require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf"),
  });

  if (!isFontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={Store}>
      <RootView />
    </Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

This the store file that I have:-

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import usersReducer from "./slices/userSlice";

export const Store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    userReducer: usersReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
});
```

And this is my user slice :-

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { StorageKeys } from "../../constant/storageKeys";

const initialState = {
  jwtToken: "",
  isAuthenticated: false,
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "UserSlice",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    authenticate: async (state, action) => {
      let jwt = action.payload.jwt;
      console.log("jwt in payload=> ", jwt);
      state.jwtToken = jwt;
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      console.log(
        "isAuthenticated state in store after authentication=>",
        state.isAuthenticated
      );
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(StorageKeys.JWT_TOKEN, jwt);
      return state;
    },
    logout: async (state) => {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem(StorageKeys.JWT_TOKEN);
      state.jwtToken = "";
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      return state;
    },
  },
});

export const { authenticate, logout } = userSlice.actions;
console.log("user slice reducer", userSlice.reducer);
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: try 
return {...state, jwtToken:action.payload.jwt,isAuthenticated:true} 
instead of handling each on its own

Answer (score 0):

Update: Well it turns out the usage of async await in the reducer functions were causing the issue. As per the official docs of redux, reducer functions are supposed to be pure and synchronous.
We need to use redux-thunk for asynchronous functionality.
After removing the async await from these functions I got to access proper updated values from the store